# How to simplify this Xpath expression?

Tags: xpath, expression, xslt-1.0, reduction

I have the following XML code :

```
<root>
   <a><l_desc/></a>
   <b><l_desc>foo</l_desc></b>
   <c><l_desc>bar</l_desc></c>
</root>
```

---

I want to match the **l_desc** nodes with **a** or **b** nodes as parent.
For now, i use this xpath expression : `//a/l_desc/.. | //b/l_desc/..`

I would prefer writing something like this : `//(a|b)/l_desc/..`
Unfortunately, this expression is invalid.

Do you have any idea for reducing the first expression ?
The xpath is to be used in an XSLT stylesheet v1.0.

Stéphan

Comment: Where in the stylesheet? As a pattern in @match? As a expression in @select?

Comment: Good question, +1. You haven't accepted the best answer, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
//l_desc[parent::a or parent::b]
```

?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to match the `l_desc` nodes with
>   a or b nodes as parent

More simple:

```
/root/a/l_desc | /root/b/l_desc
```

Or

```
/root/*[self::a | self::b]/l_desc
```

With starting `//` operator (bad design, unknown schema):

```
//a/l_desc | //b/l_desc
```

Or

```
//*[self::a | self::b]/l_desc
```

In XPath 2.0 this **is valid**

```
/root/(a|b)/l_desc
```

Comment: +1 for a good and exhaustive answer -- definitely the best of all answers.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a predicate here

```
l_desc[../a|../b]
```

Comment: this one works but i had to modify it a little : l_desc[../self::a|../self::b]

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
/*/*[self::a or self::b]/l_desc
```

**This means**:  Select all `l_desc` elements that are children of any `a` or `b` element that itself is a child of the top element of the XML document.

**Avoid**:

1. **Using the `//` abbreviation** when you know the structure of the document. `//` can be very inefficient.
2. **Using a reverse axis** (such as `parent::`) when this is not necessary. Expressions containing reverse axes are more difficult to understand and may be less efficient than expressions containing only forward axes.